# Como puedo restar dos fechas y que me devuelva horas minutos y segundos Oracle

Tags: oracle, date

Por ejemplo si resto `01/01/2017 19:30:00 - 01/01/2017 22:30:30`, en la salida debería aparecer `3 horas y 30 segundos`

Esto es lo que he probado pero no me lo devuelve con el formato que quiero, me devuelve los valores de la fecha separados en las columnas, al intentar juntarlo todo en una columna (la columna comentada) me ha salido este error:

> ```
> ORA-00904: "FECHA_UNO": identificador no válido
> ```

```
    SELECT FECHA_UNO,
       FECHA_DOS,     
       TRUNC((FECHA_DOS - FECHA_UNO)) DIFERENCIA_DIAS,
       TRUNC((FECHA_DOS - FECHA_UNO) * (24)) DIFERENCIA_HORAS,
       TRUNC((FECHA_DOS - FECHA_UNO) * (60 * 24)) DIFERENCIA_MINUTOS,
       TRUNC((FECHA_DOS - FECHA_UNO) * (60 * 60 * 24)) DIFERENCIA_SEGUNDOS
      -- TRUNC((FECHA_DOS - FECHA_UNO) - (FECHA_DOS - FECHA_UNO (24)) - (FECHA_DOS - FECHA_UNO *(24*60)) -(FECHA_DOS - FECHA_UNO *(24*60*60)) ) DIFERENCIA_TOTAL
  FROM (
SELECT TO_DATE('&1', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FECHA_UNO,
       TO_DATE('&2', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FECHA_DOS
  FROM DUAL
       );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retomando tu idea original:

```
SELECT 'Dias: ' || TO_CHAR(DIFERENCIA_DIAS, '00') || ' - ' || TO_CHAR(DIFERENCIA_HORAS, '00') || ':' || TO_CHAR(DIFERENCIA_MINUTOS, '00') || ':' || TO_CHAR(DIFERENCIA_SEGUNDOS, '00') 
        AS "Dias: DD - HH24: MI: SS"
FROM (
    SELECT FECHA_UNO,
        FECHA_DOS,
        TRUNC((FECHA_DOS - FECHA_UNO)) DIFERENCIA_DIAS,
        TRUNC(MOD((FECHA_DOS - FECHA_UNO) * 24, 24)) DIFERENCIA_HORAS,
        TRUNC(MOD((FECHA_DOS - FECHA_UNO) * (60 * 24), 60)) DIFERENCIA_MINUTOS,
        TRUNC(MOD((FECHA_DOS - FECHA_UNO) * (60 * 60 * 24), 60)) DIFERENCIA_SEGUNDOS
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            TO_DATE('01/01/2017 19:30:00', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FECHA_UNO,
            TO_DATE('02/01/2017 22:35:09', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FECHA_DOS
        FROM DUAL
        )
    )
```

[Resultado:](http://rextester.com/CTSIA92582)

> Dias:  01 -  03: 05: 09

Answer (score 0):

Puedes mirar éstos ejemplos y adaptarlos a tu necesidad en concreto.

```
select
    24 * (sysdate - to_date('2012-02-28 15:20', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi')) as diff_hours
from dual;


select
    24 * (to_date(to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi'), 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi') - to_date('2012-02-28 15:20', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi')) as diff_hours
from dual;
```

Fuente: [Misma pregunta en Stack Overflow en Ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9488475/how-can-i-get-the-difference-in-hours-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 0):

Esta es la  solución ahora solo me falta añadir los segundos, si alguno sabe como añadirlos que modifique mi respuesta.

```
SELECT FECHA_UNO,
   FECHA_DOS,       
TRUNC(ROUND(((FECHA_UNO - FECHA_DOS)*24),3))||':'||
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(ROUND((ROUND(((FECHA_UNO - FECHA_DOS)*24),3)
-TRUNC(ROUND(((FECHA_UNO - FECHA_DOS)*24),3)))*60),'mi'),'mi') "Diferencia en HORAS y MINUTOS"
FROM (
SELECT TO_DATE('&1', 'DD.MM.YY HH24:MI:SS') FECHA_UNO, -- Formato fecha: 01/01/17 19:45:00
       TO_DATE('&2', 'DD.MM.YY HH24:MI:SS') FECHA_DOS 
  FROM DUAL
       );
```