# ¿Cómo validar que un trabajador tenga por lo menos 12 meses de antigüedad en un trabajo?

Tags: plsql

Estoy iniciando en el mundo de plsql y tengo problemas al validar la antigüedad de un trabajador,  lo que intento hacer es validar que un trabajador tenga por lo menos 12 meses o más en el mismo lugar de trabajo y de no ser así mandé una excepción diciendo "no cumples con el requisito" pero desconozco cómo hacerlo, he buscado pero no he podido encontrar un ejemplo para poder continuar.

Los datos los extraigo de una BD. De la tabla Cliente_CT la cual contiene los campos:

```
Cliente_id,  Lugar_trabajo, Fecha_inicio y Fecha_salida
```

De antemano muchas gracias!

```
Procedure valida_antiguedad (p_cliente in number, p_inicio in date, p_salida in date ) Is 

Usuario number;
ValEntrada Date;
ValSalida Date ; 

Begin 

Select count (*) into usuario from cliente_ct where cliente_id = usuario;

End valida_antiguedad ;
End pkg_valida_antugüedad_trabajo;
```

Comment: Tiene que presentar tu codigo para dar una posible solucion.

Answer (score 0):

No he visto mucho de oracle pero quizá esta respuesta te pueda ayudar

Con esta lógica deberías poder saber la cantidad de meses y hacer tu validación,
utilizando la fecha de inicio y la fecha de salida.

[Como puedo restar dos fechas y que me devuelva horas minutos y segundos Oracle](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/65571/como-puedo-restar-dos-fechas-y-que-me-devuelva-horas-minutos-y-segundos-oracle)

Comment: @Huskie , No es para que copie la respuesta, es para que vea la lógica ya que al parece no tiene idea de como empezar.

Comment: Porque no he visto PostgreSQL... he visto mas las BD de SQL server y las Oracle, acaso no compartirías primero la lógica de lo que tu ya has visto o conoces?

Answer (score 0):

Antigüedad = (trunc(Fecha_salida)-trunc(Fecha_entrada))/30

En caso que la Fecha_salida sea null o mayor al sysdate, entonces la reemplazas en la fórmula por el SYSDATE

Esto te dará el número de meses, ya solo debes validar si el resultado es >= a 12